# CSS Combine Class & Style

Tags: css

I have a table row which has a class applied to it. Depending on a value set in that row I may change the background color using a style directly within the row.

```
$bground = ($a === 'a') ? '#A0A0A0' : '#ffffff';

<tr class='$class' align='center' style='background-color:$bground '>
```

Adding the style stops other css that is applied to the page from working. eg: the following stop working.

```
.res table tr:hover {
    background-color: #808080;
}

.res table tr.selected {
    background-color: #808080;
}
```

if I remove `style='background-color:$bground '>` from the row then the hover and select as expected.

Any way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: You might be running into CSS specificity rules, really you should use your script to add a CSS *class* which you then apply styling to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

firstly background-color can be shortened to background like so: `.className {background: #fff}`

next, you can combine dupe stylings like so:

```
.classOne, .classTwo, #idOne {background: #fff;}
```

next, don't assign any inline js or css. It's bad practice that leads to harder to maintain code. Just add a new id/class onto it instead.

lastly, the reason that assigning inline css stops the stylesheet is because inline css has a higher specificity value. In your stylesheet you can use elements to add to the weight:

```
div.classOne.someOtherClassItHas {background: #fff;}
```

and if that doesn't bump it up enough you can always add the `!important` rule which helps stop overrides:

```
.class {background: #fff !important;}
```

though use this sparingly and as a last resort (I recommend moving any !important rule to the bottom of the stylesheet) as it can mess with the behaviour of the stylesheet.

Comment: The `!important` rule should not be used unless absolutely necessary because it interrupts the cascading nature of CSS and creates harder to maintain code.

Comment: upvote, although I think it'd be a better answer without the "color shortening" observation (KISS)

Comment: @sorayadragon yeah I should have added that this is a last resort - will amend my post :)

Comment: @sweaver2112 thank you :) and maybe - I just like optimisations more than I probably should ahaha

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Part of my issue is using the inline style I can do that via PHP so I can dynamically create a random css colour. Doing it via a class that isn't possible.

Comment: hmm that is weird, maybe the !important rule is what you seek

Comment: @Tom great news, happy it helped :)

Comment: @Tom Although `!important` makes it work, it works because the `!important` rule **overrides the basic cascading principle of CSS**. See https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/. Please note that you **can** use PHP to create dynamic classes that will allow you to change the color as I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

No. Inline styles always override CSS. Since you have set the background color via an inline style, you cannot change it with CSS.

A solution to this problem is instead of changing the background color with an inline style, you just add another class to the tr which has a different rule for the background color.

```
.res table tr.color1 {
background-color: #A0A0A0;
}

.res table tr.color2 {
background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Then in your code, add the class to the tr:

```
$bgroundClass = ($a === 'a') ? 'color1' : 'color2';

<tr class='$class $bgroundClass' align='center'>
```